# mongoDb:Cannot find index to verify that join fields will be unique

Tags: mongodb, merge, aggregate, unique-index

Hey I need to merge my two collections,but mongo retuns "Cannot find index to verify that join fields will be unique"

1.create unique index
2.remove whenMatched/whenNotMatched

```js
db.getCollection("GeoLite2-City-Blocks-IPv4").aggregate([
    {$match:{longitude:{$gt:175,$lt:180}}},
    {$merge:{
        into:"GeoLite2-City-Locations-ja",
        on:"geoname_id",
        whenMatched: "replace",
        whenNotMatched: "insert" 
    }}
])
```

expected:retuns GeoLite2-City-Blocks-IPv4 include GeoLite2-City-Locations-ja

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The $merge aggregation stage requires a [unique index on the identifier fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#syntax):

> $merge requires a unique, index with keys that correspond to the on
>   identifier fields. Although the order of the index key specification
>   does not matter, the unique index must only contain the on fields as
>   its keys.

For your operation, there would need to exist a unique index on the `GeoLite2-City-Locations-ja` collection that contains the field `geoname_id`.

Comment: Hi Adam,Both geoLite2-City-Locations-ja and geoLite2-City-Blocks-IPv4 collections had a unique index that conatins geoname_id

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your unique index id is Type: ObjectID.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).